# ruby greater than sign getting nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I wrote the following code in Ruby, but keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass`. Not sure why it thinks `>` is a method?

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos = 0
  neg = 0
  for i in 0..lst.length
    if lst[i] > 0
      pos += 1
    elsif lst[i] < 0
      neg += 1
    end
  end
  return [pos, neg]
end
```

Comment: your index is off by one (see my answer below)

Comment: This method counts positives AND negatives. It does NOT sum negatives. Why is it called `count_positives_sum_negatives`?

Just curiosity, okay?

Comment: @Aetherus gave you the best "Ruby way" answer. Use that one.

Comment: Also, to clarify: In Ruby, `>` is a method, as is `==` and `[]` and everything else that does anything. And `nil` is an object, which is why you got your NoMethodError. Try `nil > 0` in IRB console and you'll get the same error.

Comment: We don't use `for` loops in Ruby:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not pretending I am a Ruby master when I say this. Please, don't misunderstand me. I am just repeating something I've heard when I started with Ruby a few years ago: **Learning Ruby is much more than just using Ruby syntax. One needs to explore Ruby core and try to do things the Ruby way.**

This is exactly what happens here. The code shown in the question is far from the Ruby way. And also is the code in the answer given by @manonthemat.

It could be shortened to:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  result = [0,0]
  lst.each { |el|  (el > 0 ) ? result[0] += 1 : result[1] += 1 }
  result
end
```

Or even better:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  lst.each_with_object([0,0]) { |el,arr| (el > 0) ? arr[0] += 1 : arr[1] += 1 }
end
```

In both cases, running

```
puts count_positives_sum_negatives([5,7,-1,-4,4,4,5,-3])
```

Would result in

```
[5,3]
```

Notice that the second form, using `each_with_object`, is even better than the first. Declaring an array or hash outside to use it inside a block is considered a code smell in Ruby.

I would like to point that the name of the method (`count_positives_sum_negatives`) is not good. It does not represent what the method does, since the method counts both positives and negatives, and sums none of them. Certainly `count_positives_and_negatives` would be a better name.

By the way, @manonthemat is completely right when he points that using `each` is a much better way than iterating with an index based on a range. If one really needs the index in the block, there is the `each_with_index` method to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `lst[lst.length]` is always `nil`. For example, if your `lst` is [1], then `lst[lst.length]` becomes `lst[1]` which is `nil`.

Note that `nil` is an object so it can have methods. When you call `nil > 0`, Ruby interprets it as `nil.>(0)` (you can see that `>` is a method).  `nil` does not have the method `>`, so you got the `NoMethodError`.

To get rid of boundary checking headache, you should avoid using `for` loop. Here is my implementation:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  positives, negatives = lst.partition(&:positive?)
  [positives.size, negatives.reduce(:+)]
end
```

Both `partition` and `reduce` come from the module `Enumerable`. I put the zeros into the `negatives` group. because they don't affect the result of sum, but they do affect the result of count.

Comment: Although the OP's method is named `count_positives_sum_negatives`, his original code counts both. If that's the intent, then the third line of this code would be replaced with `[positives.size, negatives.size]`. Or better, since we're counting things, maybe use the alias: `[positives.count, negatives.count]`.

Comment: Agreed, @moveson. I had commented about it in the question and mentioned it in my answer, suggesting a new name.

Comment: @moveson agree with the name change but `count` is not an alias for `size`, (though `size` is an alias for `length`). `size` is actually much faster than `count`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for the heads up--in the future I will use `#count` only when passing a block.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used Ruby, but I remember the preferred way of iterating using each

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos = 0
  neg = 0
  lst.each { |el|
    if el > 0
      pos += 1
    elsif el < 0
      neg += 1
    end
  }
  return [pos, neg]
end
```

But to answer your question, your index is off. `..` includes what's on the right. In this case the length of your list, which is one higher than the last index. That's why you get that error message.

You can still use your for-loop, but just add another ., so it's `for i in 0...lst.length`

Comment: While this answer works, the preferred Ruby way is not to use `each` at all if there is any other way to solve the problem. Here it's better solved in the answer by @Aetherus.